# Split arraylist based on calculated value of each string

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList` of strings whereby on iteration, `for(int i =0; i < arrayList.size(); i++)`. Each string is taken from a .csv file, so they are delimited by commas. One of the columns has a unix timestamp, so one string of data looks like something like this (I censored out the irrelevant values):

```
1442759243, value, value, value
```

so, as i iterate, I extract the unix time stamp to find the specific day,

```
java.util.Date time = new java.util.Date((long) timeStamp * 1000);
// gives a result of Tue Sep 15 22:38:04 SGT 2015
String date = String.valueOf(time.getDate());;
// gives the result of "15"
```

As the iteration goes on (the list is sorted by time already, so the number e.g. 15, slowly increases as the list goes), there will come a point where the next `String date` is a different value from the previous one. 
Now, on each string iteration I have set a counter that increments. When the date changes, what I want is for the counter to reset and start count again. My question is, how do I kind of "split" the arraylist so that I can reset the counter to start count again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep the previous date, and compare the current date to the previous one on each iteration:

```
int counter = 0;
String prevDate = "";
for (int i = 0; arrayList.size(); i++) {
    long timestamp = Long.parseLong(arrayList.get(i));
    Date time = new Date(timeStamp * 1000L);
    String date = String.valueOf(time.getDate());
    if (date.equals(prevDate)) {
        ++counter;
    } else {
        counter = 1;
        prevDate = date;
    }
    // Do something useful with the counter
}
```

Comment: You've missed a little something here ;-)

Comment: @laune arg, yeah. That was embarrassing :-(

Answer (score 1):

Your `for` loop is wrong. It won't compile.

You split the values in the arraylist by calling `split(",")`.

`getDate()` is deprecated. Use `Calendar`.

To reset counter, remember previous value and reset when it changes.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
int counter = 0, prevDay = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++,counter++) {
    String[] values = arrayList.get(i).split(",");
    cal.setTimeInMillis(Long.parseLong(values[0]) * 1000);
    int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    if (day != prevDay) {
        counter = 0;
        prevDay = day;
    }
    // code here
}
```